# Was the "American Symphony" played in real-time?

Tags: plot-explanation, mr-hollands-opus

At the end of Mr Holland's Opus, the eponymous Mr Holland is invited onto the stage to conduct the Premiere performance of his "An American Symphony".

Is this song supposed to have been played in real-time (e.g. it took him 30 years to compose 2.5 minutes of music) or are we merely watching *edited highlights* of a [larger work](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dmp92FUPNz4)?

Comment: I'd always presumed the latter, but I've no proof.  Then again, it was the plot that he never had the time he wanted to work on it.

Comment: @Radhil - True, but scoring less than 10 seconds of music **per year** doesn't seem especially onerous to me

Comment: Also true... well, someone had to put it all together behind his back, right?  Possibly they only included the bits that looked most complete?

Comment: @Radhil - But then, how did he know which bits to conduct?

Comment: Eh, Rule of Drama.  I've got nothing.

Comment: The music is continuous so it is actually a complete composition, but surely the dramatic intent is that it's a longer work. Curious conducting by Richard Dreyfuss :-| Hilarious to see the audience members hyperventilating.